# How to create a root component for making a request regardless of page url in next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am currently trying to make a request to server after refreshing page or opening this in a new tab.
For example after using f5 I want to make a request. But I don't want to make a request after every routing.
Basically after refreshing I want to make a request to see if user is authenticated using cookie on the request.
But It appears next.js doesn't have a root component like pure react.js(App.js). I searched documentations and different websited. But I couldn't find it. I don't want to write request code to every file.
Here is my files:

[image: Files]

Is there a way to do this?

I want to do a request on every link possible (/login, /register, /profile, /) So I need a root component which is mounted on every link (only once).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create _app.ts file in your pages directory. and add the following snippet.This component is the root component in next js and it any function you write here will be executed once depending on how you call this function.

for more info, check this link in Next Js docs https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app

```js
// import App from 'next/app'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

// Only uncomment this method if you have blocking data requirements for
// every single page in your application. This disables the ability to
// perform automatic static optimization, causing every page in your app to
// be server-side rendered.
//
// MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
//   // calls page's `getInitialProps` and fills `appProps.pageProps`
//   const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);
//
//   return { ...appProps }
// }

export default MyApp
```

Comment: With using useEffect(()=> {}, []),  this does exactly what I want thank you. But _app.ts gives error for returning component. So I used _app.tsx and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a function to wrap around your "normal" pages to use it. You can pass arguments, in my example a country option.

```
export default function Layout(
   {country, children}: PropsWithChildren<{country: Country }>) {
     /* your code inside here */
    return (
       <main className={country} data-gtm-block="main">
        {children}
      </main>
    );
   }
```

and then use it like that for every page

```
export default function AboutPage({ country }: { country: Country }) {
   return (
     <Layout country={country}>
       /* your code in here */
     </Layout>
   );
}

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (context: GetStaticPropsContext) => {
  const country = getCountry(context.locale);
  return {
    props: {
      country
    }
  };
};
```